# rename multiple column of a dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to rename some columns in a dataframe that I'm providing in a Seq.
I'm using below method:

```
def prefixColumns(dataframe: DataFrame, columnPrefix: String, cols: Seq[String]) : DataFrame = {
    for (column <- dataframe.columns){
        if(cols.contains(column)){
            dataframe.withColumnRenamed(column, columnPrefix + "_" + column)
        }
    }
    dataframe
}
```

and calling
`prefix(products, "products", Seq(col1,col2,col3,col4))`

It is only renaming `col4` as `products_col4` and other columns are left as is.

Can someone suggest me a way to do this in scala?

I want to rename only the columns provided in the Seq and other columns of dataframe as is.

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not rename anything because `withColumnRenamed` does not transform the object it is called on. It returns a new object with the column renamed. Let's check that:

```scala
Seq("id", "id2")
val cols = Seq("id", "id2")
val df = spark.range(1).select('id, 'id as "x", 'id as "id2", 'id as "id3")
df.show
```

```
+---+---+---+---+
| id|  x|id2|id3|
+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  0|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+---+
```

```scala
prefixColumns(df, "X", col).show()
```

```
+---+---+---+---+
| id|  x|id2|id3|
+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  0|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+---+
```

But you can adjust your function a little bit to make it work:

```scala
def prefixColumns(dataframe: DataFrame, columnPrefix: String, cols: Seq[String]) : DataFrame = {
    var result = dataframe
    for (column <- dataframe.columns){
        if(cols.contains(column)){
            // we assign the renamed df to the result variable
            result = result.withColumnRenamed(column, columnPrefix + "_" + column)
        }
    }
    result
}

prefixColumns(df, "X", col).show()
```

```
+----+---+-----+---+
|X_id|  x|X_id2|id3|
+----+---+-----+---+
|   0|  0|    0|  0|
+----+---+-----+---+
```

NB: another way at it is to use `select` like this. No for loops:

```scala
dataframe.select( dataframe.columns.map(c => 
    if(cols contains c) col(c).alias(columnPrefix + "_" + c) else col(c) 
) : _*)
```